# Only default syntax highlighting works

Tags: neovim, syntax-highlighting

I'm using nVim `v0.4.3`

I can't seem to get anything but the default syntax highlighting working. (I'm especially trying to get `yats` typescript syntax highlighting working)

I've tried disabling every plugin.
Then every plugin except for `HerringtonDarkholme/yats.vim`

There's absolutely no difference in the highlighting. (And the default leaves a lot to be desired).

I've also checked `:scriptnames` to ensure yats wasn't being loaded without my knowledge etc...

Without yats
[image: without yats]

With yats
[image: with yats]

This is what I have enabled right now

[image: current plugins]

What can I do differently?

Comment: Are you sure yats is supposed to highlight more? Could be that this is just how it highlights stuff?

Comment: Can you give an example of something which should be highlighted differently in your two screenshots?

Comment: @MartinTournoij First of all, I just wanted to say you're awesome for always being so prompt!!! Thank you too @Rich

I'd be lying if I said I knew what `yats` syntax highlighting should look like but here's a quick comparison

https://imgur.com/a/yRpdPZX

You'll notice that on vim there's no highliting for operators, brackets, constants, destructured variables, method calls.

It's not the end of the world, but my inclination is that `Yats` is not actually active. Am I just expecting too much from `Yats`?

Comment: Usually syntax highlighting for Vim tends to be more minimal, I rather prefer it like that since it's less distracting, but tastes differ in that regard. Sometimes there are options to enable/disable stuff; I looked at yats but there's no docs and the highlighting is subdivided in many files, so I'm not sure if there are any other than `g:yats_host_keyword` mentioned in the README. You could consider asking the plugin maintainers though, if you want to be sure.

Comment: @MartinTournoij thanks again. I didn't realize that re: `enable/disable` features.

Thanks a tonne for your support. I'll check in w/ them and share my findings here once I'm done. Thanks again